# Spark SQL broadcast for multiple join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know how to bradcast for 2 tables join, like:

```
SELECT  /*+ MAPJOIN(Table1) */ COLUMN 
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.key = Table2.key
```

But is there a way to use broadcast for 3 tables join?

```
SELECT  /* ？ */ COLUMN 
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON ...
            JOIN Table3 ON ...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general case, small tables will automatically be broadcasted based on the configuration `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`.

And broadcast join algorithm will be chosen.

spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold defaults to 10 MB (i.e. 10L * 1024 * 1024) and Spark will check what join to use (see JoinSelection execution planning strategy).